# Golang OpenGL Vertex Struct

Tags: opengl, go

I'm working on an OpenGL application in Golang and am having some odd issues with getting Vertices to render properly after converting them to a struct instead of an array of point positions.

As an array of points, it works well though after changing it to a struct the behaviour is quite odd. It either flickers and then disappears or doesn't appear at all on launch.

I imagine I'm just doing something wrong somewhere in the OpenGL calls, though I can't imagine what it is. I'm fairly certain that doing it in this manner would work well in C++.

I've attached the before and after code of what I changed.

Thanks for any and all help =)

EDIT:: Oh, this behaviour happens when I change the *12 in the buffer length to *8, I was originally trying to do 3D coord, but that has the same effect.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGCiP.png) |||  [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBKOU.png)

Comment: `len(s.vertexData) * 12` looks wrong for me. Since there are two floats per vertex, shouldn't you multiply with 8 instead of 12?

Comment: yeah, I had already fixed that after taking the screenshot. 

I've been messing around and I think it may be a limitation to how golang handles structs. 

Keeping the buffer as a basic array without structs works flawlessly though changing it to structs gives me issues =x

Comment: What happens if you change line 70 to `&s.vertexData[0]`? That changed from your original